# Mouse position interactive image

Tags: jquery

I currently have an image which updates according to mouse position. Check out [http://www.fore6.com/?p=533][1]

[1]: http://www.fore6.com/?p=533 to give you an idea of what I mean.

The issue is that I have multiple images that I need to apply this to, and each image needs to animate independently of the other. At the moment they all animate at the same time, i.e; they need to animate independently because the mouse position will be different for each image!

I can get it working by repeating the function for each image and changing the variables, but that is an awful lot of code. How can I do this within one function?

I'm guessing that I may need to put each image into an array or use $(this), but can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code I am using is below:

```
var imageX = null;
var imageY = null;

imageX = $('.anim-photo').offset().left;
imageY = $('.anim-photo').offset().top;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var mousePos = new Array(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    interact(mousePos, ["0px", "-288px", "-576px"]);
})

function interact(mouseCord, aniCord) {
    if (mouseCord[0] < imageX && mouseCord[1] < imageY){ // Box-1
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX && mouseCord[0] < imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] < imageY){ // Box-2
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] < imageY){ // Box-3
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" 0px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] < imageX && mouseCord[1] > imageY && mouseCord[1] < imageY+357){ // Box-4
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" -360px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX && mouseCord[0] < imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] > imageY && mouseCord[1] < imageY+357){ // Box-5
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" -360px");

}else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] > imageY && mouseCord[1] < imageY+357){ // Box-6
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" -360px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] < imageX && mouseCord[1] > imageY+357){ // Box-7
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[0]+" -720px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX && mouseCord[0] < imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] > imageY+357){ // Box-8
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[1]+" -720px");

} else if (mouseCord[0] > imageX+285 && mouseCord[1] > imageY+357){ // Box-9
    $(".anim-photo").css("background-position", aniCord[2]+" -720px");
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you need  just one image element like this:

```
<img id="face" src="face-follower/0.jpg" alt="face">
```

assume that we have a set of images with names like:000.jpg , 001.jpg and ... in which:

1. first num indicates that mouse position is above middle if 1, and below middle if 0.
2. second num shows that mouse if left of middle if 0 and right of it if 1.
3. third num devides each quarter of page to 4 sections with 22.5 deg angle

get the center of your image and check the position of cursor with the center of image.
then according to position create the name of image:

```
var element = $('#face');
var top = element.offset().top + element.height()/2;
var left = element.offset().left + element.width()/2;

var a = 0
, b = 0 
, c = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function()
{
var x=Math.floor(event.clientX - left);
var y=Math.floor(event.clientY - top);
if(x > 0)
  a = 1;
else if(x < 0)
  a = 0;
if(y > 0)
  b = 0;
else if(y < 0)
  b = 1;
if(Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y))
{
  c = 2;
  if(Math.abs(x)>Math.abs(y)*2.4)
    c = 3;

}
else if(Math.abs(y) > Math.abs(x))
{
  c = 1;
  if (Math.abs(y)>Math.abs(x)*2.4)
    c = 0;
}
```

now that you have whole 3 characters of image name, change the source of it
      element.attr('src','face-follower/'+a+b+c+'.jpg');
    });
[working sample](https://github.com/ussr1287/alihaghighatkhah/tree/master)